# de Rham cohomology of the Grassmannian bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, grassmannian, jet-bundles

Let $X$ be a smooth $n+m$ dimensional manifold and $\pi:Y\rightarrow X$ the bundle whose fibre over any $x\in X$ is the Grassmann manifold of all $m$ dimensional subspaces of $T_xX$. This is equivalent to the manifold $J^1(X,m)$ of all first order contact elements of dimension $m$, also called the space of order $1$ jets of $m$ dimensional submanifolds in $X$.

I am interested in knowing the de Rham cohomology $H^\ast_{\mathrm{dR}}(Y)$ of the total space of this bundle in terms of the de Rham cohomology $H^\ast_{\mathrm{dR}}(X)$ of $X$.

I assume this is computable and have been computed, but I cannot find it anywhere and I am not familiar enough with algebraic topology to compute it myself.

Comment: @Travis That only deals with the homology/cohomology of the fiber. In general, the question involves characteristic classes. You might look at Chapter 4 of Bott/Tu and the discussion of $\Bbb P(E)$ and flag manifolds.

Comment: @TedShifrin You're right---I read the question too quickly. I've removed the link to avoid confusion.